# Exclude comments from a WP_Query object?

Tags: wp-query, comments, wp-comment-query

I have noticed that the default WP_Query object also contains all of a post's comments.

```
global $wp_query;

print_r($wp_query->comments);
// Prints an object containing all of a post's comments
```

From my understanding, WordPress somehow combines a post query and a comments query into one `WP_Query` object, and then displays a post's comments by reading the `$wp_query->comments` object.

However, I need to query comments and order them by passing advanced query args. So I use `WP_Comment_Query` to create a new object that contains all of a post's comments in the order I need them.

```
$args = array(      
    'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query($args);

print_r($comments);
// Prints an object containing all comments matching the query
```

But now it seems that using `WP_Comment_Query` basically makes WordPress load all of a post's comments **twice**.

Obviously, from a performance perspective, this is undesirable, seeing as I don't actually use the default `WP_Query`'s comment object to display my comments.

So I'm wondering: Is it possible to prevent the `WP_Query` from grabbing a post's comments, so that I can later grab them 'manually' using `WP_Comment_Query`? And so, preventing the same comments from being grabbed from the database twice?

Comment: The `$wp_query->comments` is sort of explained [here](https://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012). You might wanna take a look into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you actually find a case where there are any real comments in the wp-query object after running a normal query?

If you examine the code in class-wp-query.php, you should find that the comments field only is populated with comments when a "comments-feed" is being queried for.

In normal operation, comments are not retrieved by the WP_Query, but instead retrieved by using WP_Comment_Query, and this does not happen until your theme calls the comments_template() function.

As such, you can use the 'comments_template_query_args' filter to filter the arguments passed to that class before the comments are displayed on the page. This won't affect the comments feed, because those are indeed populated by the main WP_Query, but only for the comments feed case.

Comment: After doing some more testing and inserting `print_r($wp_query->comments);` in various parts on my page, I found that the `$wp_query->comments` object is only filled **after** `comments_template()` is  called.


It seems that I might have misunderstood exactly **when** the `$wp_query->comments` object is filled, as I tested this inside my custom `comments_template` code.


So just to make sure I understood your answer correctly, does this mean that running a custom `WP_Comment_Query` does in fact, **not** add an extra SQL query to my database when fetching comments?

Comment: If you run a separate comments query instead of using the filter to modify the built in one, then yes, a separate query will be run. Again, examine the comments_template() code to see how it runs the comment query. You can use the filter to modify the built in one instead of running your own custom separate one.

Comment: It seems that I unknowingly circumvented my problem by loading the comments with AJAX, and never actually calling `comments_template` in my theme. However, this information will still be useful when creating the no-js backup for the comment system! Thank you!